# Using MailGun API - Batch Sending in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, mailgun

For a project in Yii2 framework I use MailGun.
Here I want to use MailGun Batch. I have searched all over the internet for an example or tutorial but it still doesn't work and I get an error message at every step.
This is my post function where the emails should be sent. and my error message below.
Hopefully you can help me with it

```
public function actionEmail() {
        $dataCollection = Trace::getOrderItemCollection();

        $configurator = new HttpClientConfigurator();
        $configurator->setApiKey( 'key-******API-KEY*******' );
        $configurator->setDebug( true );
        $mgClient     = new Mailgun( $configurator, new ArrayHydrator() );
        $batchMessage = $mgClient->messages()->getBatchMessage( "************MAilAdres******************.mailgun.org" );

        $batchMessage->setFromAddress( 'info@myemail.com' );
        $batchMessage->setSubject( 'Test-Subject' );
        $batchMessage->setHtmlBody( '<html>This is a test HTML text.</html>' );
        $batchMessage->setTextBody( "This is a test body text." );

        foreach ( Trace::getData( $dataCollection ) as $item ) {
            $batchMessage->addToRecipient( $item['email'] );
        }

        $batchMessage->finalize();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems are using `mailgun/mailgun-php` package.

As decribed in its documentation [here](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/master/src/Message/README.md#usage---batch-message) try this:

```
$mg = Mailgun::create( '**API-KEY**' );

// Setup batch
$batchMessage = $mg->messages()->getBatchMessage( "**DOMAIN**" );
$batchMessage->setFromAddress( "**EMAIL-FROM**");
$batchMessage->setSubject( "A Batch Message from the PHP SDK!" );
$batchMessage->setHtmlBody( '<html>This is the text body of the message!</html>' );
$batchMessage->setTextBody( "This is the text body of the message!" );

// Add receivers
foreach($receivers as $receiverEmail) {
    $batchMessage->addToRecipient( $receiverEmail);
}

// Send all that remain in queue
$batchMessage->finalize();
```

Remember, using `$batchMessage->addToRecipient()` adds a message to the queue. Every time the queue hits 1000 recipients it will send the mails. Make sure to call `$batchMessage->finalize();` to send all mails that are remaining in the queue.

Also note that when testing this with a sandbox domain, every receiver must be an authorized email address. Or else you may run into [this "Check your inputs!"](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/369) error.